# Mat Dialog changing it's backdrop after being opened

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-dialog

This is my site before opening the dialog:
[image]

And this after:
[image]

This is the relevant content of my styles.scss:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #303030;
  color: white;
}
```

And this is my theme of the project:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();

$theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 900);
$theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-grey, 50);
$theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme: mat-dark-theme($theme-primary, $theme-accent, $theme-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

The problem only occurs, when scrolling down a bit. At the top of the page I have a mat-tab-nav-bar.

Update: Bug occurring in Chrome but not in Safari

Comment: stackblitz please?

Comment: can you try to delete this line and test again?  styles.scss:  background: #303030;

Comment: @Marc without background color attribute, I don't have the problem. But I want the grey background. Do you have an idea how to change background color without having this bug?

Comment: You can pick the 'grey' area with "web developer toolbar" and then you got the element and its class.   ".mat-drawer" or whatever. If you know this, you can explicit set the background value for this class in your styles.scss

Comment: Aakash Garg  is right: we need a stackblitz  :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Marc! I've removed the background color attribute from body and html and added it to mat.figure and mat-grid-list.mat-grid-list. This has solved my problem!